# How do I grab chat room transcripts every 1hr and automatically post them in vBulletin?

Tags: post, chat, vbulletin

Is there a way to grab chat room transcripts every 1hr and automatically post them in vBulletin? I am currently using envole as my chat plugin for my wordpress site.

What method is best to get this done accurately. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the chat system posts logs to mySQL then you can use an Ajax request to start posting it into vBulletin as a thread under, say a Chat Room archive forum.. if that is what you mean?

Comment: yes i understand that but i don't think evolve stores it in the mySQL. I guess i can use another chat plugin can you recommend me a good 1 please.

Comment: Sorry just check vBulletin.org and check the modules and mods on the site. You could use many scripts though on HotScripts (although this site has sort of lost value) also CodeCanyon.. you just need a MySQL and PHP chat system and then your own cron job and user perms that collates the data which pings and places the data inside the thread.